# css3 div 'pulse'

Tags: animation, html, css

How does one make a div/input flash or 'pulse'? Say for example a form field has an invalid value entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS3 something like **[on this page](http://www.zurb.com/article/221/css3-animation-will-rock-your-world)**, you can add the pulsing effect to a class called `error`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes error {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

.error { 
  opacity: 0.75; 
  -webkit-animation-name: error; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10; 
}
```

A **[YouTube demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ybrbLnftps)** if you're not on Safari, Chrome or another browser the above works on. The demo makes use of `:hover` to start the animation.

You can add the above class to invalid entries.

For example, this is very simple with the  **[jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)**:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").validate();
});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mharen/3xnLv/)**

Comment: ah very good.   I couldn't find one to make the element flash -- do you know of any examples of that?

Comment: @hvgotcodes - jQuery has some [ **simple form validation options** ](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). Combine that with the technique above. I edited in a simplified example.

Comment: not using jquery -- its amazing google wont show me some 'flash' enabled by webkit...